# iOS Core Bluetooth - Invalid Handle Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm making an iOS app with Core Bluetooth. My device has a central role and several other iOS peripheral devices have a handful of characteristics. A peripheral's characteristics include 1 Read, 2 Notify and a Write. I'm running into an "Invalid Handle" error for the Read characteristic in the `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` delegate callback. If I ignore the error and display the characteristics value, it works fine. However, when I go to write to the Write characteristic, I get a "Handle is invalid" error in the `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` delegate callback. I can't simply ignore this error because I've verified that peripheral I'm writing to does not actually get written.

I know I can solve this problem by manually resetting the Bluetooth on either of the iOS devices (peripheral or central). And, I don't know how to systematically recreate this bug. It happens seemingly randomly, but it's not uncommon.

Does anyone have any insight as to the cause of this problem? Or a possible workaround? Even a way to programmatically simulate a Bluetooth reset?